# proguard warning cannot solve

Tags: android, proguard

> Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of
>   [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmk] (with 1 known super classes)
>   and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes)

Comment: What are your google dependencies?

Comment: i have add only firebase but it show me this line of error

Comment: Hey, I am getting the exact error. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I solved this error by change the version code to old it work when set old version